# Running 14.04 Cannot install Brother DCP J4110DW printer

Tags: printing

The DCP J4110DW is not listed.in the faq's
I have tried to set up this printer.
14.04 can see printer, but no communication even via usb cable.
Print test page/ print self test/ clean nozzles
Printbox message printer "idle", Jobs being created but not listed.
Brother cups solutions rejected by  Software centre as being unreliable.